# How can i get a value between two date from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an application for hotel booking. How can i fetch data between two dates.

Here is my Controller logic.

```
public function GetMarriageDate(){

   $frm = $this->input->post('from');

   $to = $this->input->post('to');

   $date=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_marriagebooking` WHERE (to_date BETWEEN '$frm' AND $to')UNIONSELECT * FROM `tbl_marriagebooking` WHERE (from_date BETWEEN '$frm' AND to')");

   $count=$date->num_rows();return $count;

}
```

My dataBase `table(tbl_marriageBooing)`

```
id   name        to_date        from_date

1    name 1     2014-11-15    2014-11-18

2    name 2     2014-11-20    2014-11-24

3    name 3     2014-11-26     2014-11-30
```

My problem is that if some one selects date `to=2014-11-20`  from `2014-11-23` in this condition, sql returns or selects  `id = 2` because `2014-11-20` from `2014-11-24` are  booked.

Comment: Ok then what is your expected result?

Comment: I want if user date  between booking date than they return 1. 

1 means date not available. ex

user date 20214-11-21 from 2014-11-23
and booking date in database 

2014-11-20 from 2014-11-24

Comment: Not sure I understood what is the expected result but did you try to use the SQL `CASE/THEN` statement? Might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$frm = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('from')));
$to =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('to')));
$date=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_marriagebooking WHERE DATE(to_date) >= '$to' AND DATE(from_date) <= '$frm'");
```

For both date exact match

```
$date=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_marriagebooking WHERE DATE(to_date) = '$to' AND DATE(from_date) = '$frm'");
```

Comment: this is query return same response. I want if user date between   
booking date than they return 1.

1 means date not available.